# How to make a texField open with click of a button?

Tags: android

I am new to android programming and there are a few things I don't quite know how to do yet.  I am doing a course on udemy and was trying to put together everything I have learned up to a certain point.
What I am trying to do is have the user click on a button (i have 12) and have it bring up a textField where they can enter two numbers.   I just want to be able to get the user's two numbers and i'm pretty sure I can figure out the rest ( I hope).  I just don't understand how to go about doing this.
Any help would be much appreciated. Basically all I want to do is to be able to have the user click on one of the 12 buttons and be asked to enter two values, then take those values and perform a calculation on it.

Comment: Can you please post your activity xml as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml could be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/b_ok"
        android:text="Click Me"/>

    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/et_showme"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and your activity could be like this:

```
package com.william.kinaan.welcomeback;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Test1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button b_ok;
    private EditText et_showme;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test1);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        this.b_ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_ok);
        this.b_ok.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.et_showme = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_showme);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        this.et_showme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You this seems to work.  Can you explain what does the " initialize();" do if you don't mind.

Comment: @NarainRamjieawan the `initialize()` is a custom method to define your view objects (in this case button and edit text). and it also set the listener for the button to the current class. I normally prefer to have a custom method for initialisation just to make the code more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Activity that has 2 EditTexts 
When user click a button the Activity is started and user can enter the Numbers

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand what you mean.  Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Create an Activity that opens when user click the Button. Inside the Activity is where user enters numbers and Process it. Also you only need to have a Activity but create perform different processes on the number user typed based on the Button clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv_id"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:text="sample text"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click"
        android:id="@+id/click"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And in your activity, you can do like this.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click);
        final EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv_id);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hmm so for every button I would have to have that "EditText" field?

Comment: As far as you can process the user inputs individually for each button click, You can have one EditText and use it for multiple buttons..

Comment: I tried your code sample and nothing happens when I click the button:

Comment: You are doing something wrong then. Its working perfectly fine

Comment: I guess so.  I'm gonna keep at it.  Thanks for the help.  The only difference is I have "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);" instead of "setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);"

Comment: Update your question with your code.. Will look into it